# How to change a chart title from Excel 2003 using c# and .net 4?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0, excel-2003

In my computer I've Excel 2007 and all works fine but when I pass it to the production computer occurs a problem defining a chart title because it has Excel 2003 instead of 2007.

I've tried 2 aproaches, using chart wizard:

```
chartPage.ChartWizard(Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,"",Type.Missing,Type.Missing,)
```

and the HasTitle:

```
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = xlWorkSheet.Name.Replace(" Month", "");
```

---

Both work on my computer but not on production giving the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Chart.set_HasTitle(Boolean RHS)
   at DailyInfo.Program.cleanSheets(String inputExcelFile, String outputExcelFile)
   at DailyInfo.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

---

How can I update the Chart Title of a Excel 2003 file using C# .net 4.0?